# How do I change an image source to show the image in the div

Tags: html, json, image, url

This is the current code that shows the url (data-owner_logo) in my div after indexing json. Rather than just show the url string I'd like the actual logo image to show in the div:

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    $('#show').html($(this).attr('data-owner') + 
        '<br>' + $(this).attr('data-owner_logo') + 
        '<br>' + $(this).attr('data-url'));
});
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Please add jquery tag (I can't because right now another edit is awaiting approval)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the src attribute of an IMG element to the value, then it will load the image and display it.

Comment: Hi neuhaus - is that the same with using href , not sure where I put the text to replace the url e.g. replace url with "More info here"?